# WinRT Exception on SetSourceAsync

Tags: windows-runtime, winui-3

I'm running into an exception in C# code intended to set the contents of a WinUI3 Image object. I don't know how to interpret the exception message.

Here's the code:

```
using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync();

var memStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(responseStream, memStream);
memStream.Seek(0);

var retVal = new Image();

var source = new BitmapImage();
// the exception is thrown on the next line
await source.SetSourceAsync( outStream );
retVal.Source = source;
```

The exception message is

> Unspecified error (Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.)

What's weird is that calls to this code sometimes succeed and sometimes don't, even when the exact same parameters (which define the Uri that the response stream is derived from) are specified and the exact same response is received.

That suggests there's something in the context of the call that's the problem. The cases that succeed are when the code is called from a viewmodel in a WinUI3 test app. The cases that fail are when the code is called from a custom WinUI3 control I've written.

I thought there might be a "called from the wrong thread" problem but in both the success and failure cases the code is being called from the main UI thread.

Another odd thing is that the code throwing the exception is contained within a try/catch block (not shown for simplicity)...but the catch block doesn't catch the exception. Instead, it gets caught by the unhandled exception handler generated by WinUI3.

Advice on how to proceed with researching what's going wrong -- or potential solutions! -- would be appreciated, thanx.

Comment: (1) I assume `outStream` is a typo for `memStream`. Is it possible that the stream received from ReadAsInputStreamAsync does not contain a supported bitmap format? (2) Share the `try..catch` block that encloses this code so we can see whether it is set up properly.

Comment: Thanx @RaymondChen for the suggestion. I believe the problem has to do with where the ImageSource is being created before SetSourceAsync() is called. If it's created within the context of a UIElement it works correctly, if it's created outside such a context it throws the exception. I'm not sure that theory is correct, though, which is why I haven't proposed it as an answer.